# MS Publisher 2013 mail merge - date field in excel file format issue

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, mail-merge, microsoft-publisher

The date field in the source Excel file is formated in long format, 23 April, 2014.  But in the mail merge results from Publisher 2013 it goes to 2014-04-27 00:00:00.   The format control in the Mailing tabs is grayed out.  Is there anyway to show the desired format?

Comment: How exactly is the cell formatted in Excel? To find out, right click on the cell, select "Format Cells..." and go to the "Number tab."

Comment: Peter, its formatted as Date  March 14, 2012 in the type field in Excel.

Comment: Do you mean that the text, in Excel, appears in the cell as DD MMMM, 2014 (e.g., "23 April, 2014") even though it is formatted as MMMM DD, YYYY (e.g., "March 14, 2012")? Also, when you say "The format control in the Mailing tabs is grayed out." You are referring to Publisher, not Excel, correct?

Comment: In excel I formated the date column to give April 27, 2014 when I enter 4/27/2014.

Comment: I am using Publisher 2013 for the merged document.

Comment: Is there anyway to put a screen shot in these comments?

Comment: You can edit your original question and add screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

When viewing the field - *NOT* in  Data Preview mode - you can select the field and change the format in the mailing tab.

[image: .gif showing how to format dates]

Comment: Thank you for answering a year old unanswered question, if you have access please attach screenshots so the answer is more clear. Thumbs up for the effort

Comment: I went and got popcorn to enjoy with the movie.  :-)